# What chapter of the Abhidharmartha Pradipika talks about infinite universes?

Tags: philosophy, texts, realms, religion, scripture

I've been looking into Buddhist concepts and the topic of infinite universes in existence popped up, and the Buddhist text called the "Abhidharmartha Pradipika" talks about infinite universes? And I was wondering what chapter/verse talks about it so I could look more into it.

Comment: By mentioning "Abhidharmartha Pradipika", are you referring to the book written by Dr. Amaradasa Rathnapala?

Comment: Yeah that Buddhist text. I've talked to some Buddhists about it and it's pretty popular among them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in ...

1. [AN 3.80](https://suttacentral.net/an3.80/en/sujato).
2. [The Path of Purification](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf), Six Recollection, Recollection into
   Buddha's Value.(Visuddhimagga ChaAnussatiNiddesa
   BuddhanussatiKatha).
3. AbhidhammatthaVibhavini [5th Chapter](https://sutta.men/?rm.r.147.165.0.5.).
4. etc.

[Abhidhanappadipika](https://sutta.men/?rm.index.0.0.0.0.%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%98%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99) is a Glossary explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Abhidharmarthapradipika can be read here in four volumes, but it is all in Sinhalese. You will need to find a translator or someone who can read it for you. I don't know if it has been translated.

http://m.budaedu.org/ebooks/p6-2-SR.php (search this for "PRADIPIKA")
http://ftp.budaedu.org/ebooks/pdf/SR041.pdf (Vol. 1)

The rest of the volumes are on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Anguththara Nkaya 3.2.3.10. Ananda wagga 10. chulanika suththa. sahassi loka dhathu, dwi sahassi loka dhathu > Describe galaxies.

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Could you add more description in English? Thanks.